# Resource governor for 'prepared statements' exceeded

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, sybase, jdbctemplate

We are using Spring JDBCTemplate 2.5 version and getting below exception when used batchupdate method.

```
Exception thrown!
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT SERVICE WHERE CREATE_TIME >= ? AND CREATE_TIME < ?]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [-685]; [Sybase][JDBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Resource governor for 'prepared statements' exceeded; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: [Sybase][JDBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Resource governor for 'prepared statements' exceeded
               at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:124)
               at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:322)
               at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:607)
               at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:641)
               at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:670)
               at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:678)
               at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:710)
               at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate.query(SimpleJdbcTemplate.java:187)
```

Could you please let me know if it is known issue? if so how to get it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://dcx.sybase.com/1101/en/dbadmin_en11/max-statement-count-option.html):

> Applications that use prepared statements can receive the error "Resource governor for 'prepared statements' exceeded" if the prepared statements are not explicitly dropped once they are no longer required.

So you probably should review your code for non-closed prepared statement or adjust your sybase "max_statement_count" parameter. The later seems more likely as you are using `JdbcTemplate`s

Comment: Also note that 2.5 is a pretty old version, you probably should upgrade

Comment: thanks for your reply. do you mean JdbcTemplace does not drop the statement or is there any config param available to fine tune it if it takes longer time. please suggest

Comment: AFAIK, `JdbcTemplate` does its job correctly, but 1/ you are using a really old version and 2/ you didn't post your code so maybe you did misuse it